# node.js / io.js - How can I consistently log a request's flow considering domains are being deprecated?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-domains

I've been using domains to add a `request id` to my logs.
This is very convenient because it means I don't have to pass my request object everywhere, but I can still see the request context that a db query ran in, and I can follow the process each request goes throw regardless of which layers in my code it accessed.

Since [domains are being deprecated](https://github.com/nodejs/io.js/issues/66), what are my alternatives to preserving this capability ?

Thanks